# I can't generate a model either migration in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration, activeadmin

I have a rails project and i want to add a new table and also make changes in one table which is already in the project.
From the terminal and inside the folder of the existing rails project I write this:

```
Mini-1:arbinet anna$ rails generate model PriceRate profitable_routes_id:int normalized_rate:float normalized_payout:float margin:float old_rate:float old_payout:float old_margin:float
```

And also this for the migration:

```
Mini-1:arbinet anna$ rails generate migration ChangeColumnsFromProfitableRoutes
```

But for both I get this message:

```
 Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                 # Default: /Users/anna/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]        # Path to a application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]      # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile]           # Don't create a Gemfile
      [--skip-bundle]            # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git]               # Skip Git ignores and keeps
  -O, [--skip-active-record]     # Skip Active Record files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets]         # Skip Sprockets files
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]      # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                 # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]  # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                 # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev]                    # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge]                   # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
  -T, [--skip-test-unit]         # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--old-style-hash]         # Force using old style hash (:foo => 'bar') on Ruby >= 1.9

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

And I don't have any clue why, but it was working when I create the other tables.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html

Answer (score 2):

You should call the 'rails' command from within the proper docroot (folder) of your app.

So if your app lives in `/pub/www/mycoolapp/` you should do: `cd /pub/www/mycoolapp/` and run the rails commands from there

Comment: arbinet is the root folder of my app

Comment: What do you get when you type `rails console`?

Comment: Do you see the `app/` folder in your `arbinet` if you type `ls -la`?

Comment: yes i can see it: drwxr-xr-x  12 anna  staff    408 Mar  8 14:52 app

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27936/discussion-between-yossarian-and-anna)

Answer (score 2):

A little bin later, but maybe it is a problem that any of you may have.

Run this command inside your app root folder

```
bundle exec rake rails:update:bin
```

And enjoy coding!!